# How to take a screenshot in KDE Plasma Ubuntu?

Tags: plasma, screenshot

I am new to Plasma and I don't know how to take a screenshot. From what I've seen there isn't any shortcut for that so I would like to create one, if only I knew how to do it.

Comment: You haven't mentioned any OS or release details, but just pressing PrtScr on my Kubuntu 20.04.1 system will take a screenshot & opens a `spectacle` window offering to save it, or take another (with/without delay, include mouse pointer, area, current screen, both screens, etc).

Comment: @guiverc I am sorry. I have Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE Plasma GUI. With the default GUI the *prt sc* for screenshot worked.

Answer (score 11):

You can run the program called `spectacle`.

In case you have to install it manually, just type the following command in your terminal and follow the instructions:

```
sudo apt install kde-spectacle
```

This is what it looks like in KDE Plasma V5.27 as of 2024:
[image]

Comment: It worked for Fedora 35 (Plasma)

Comment: should work everywhere, this is KDE's standard program

Answer (score 7):

These keyboard shortcuts are the default in Kubuntu 20.04.1:

To take a screenshot of the entire screen (all displays), the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd>.

To take a screenshot of the active window, the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd>.

Screenshots taken from keyboard shortcuts are automatically saved in `~/Pictures`.

You can customize the keyboard shortcuts for screenshots under **System Settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > Screenshots**.

Comment: This works in Kubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 1):

You can configure win+shift+s to take a screenshot using the steps below. The screenshot is copied to the clipboard so it can be pasted into other applications such as lowriter. The screenshots are also saved in a folder,  ~/Pictures/screenshots , with a time stamp for later reference.

Steps

```
# Go to Custom Shortcuts
K Menu -> System Settings -> Workspace -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts
# Create a new custom group called Spectacle
-> Edit -> New Group -> give it a name, say, "Spectacle"
-> Click on the checkbox next to Spectacle
# create new custom shortcut(s)
-> Edit > New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL
--> Give it a name, say, "PrintScreen Clipboard Rectangular"
--> Comment: Copy the screenshot into clipboard and also save it to a file.
--> Trigger: Meta+Shift+S
# The output directory will be created if it does not already exist.
--> Action: Command/URL: spectacle -bcr -o "$HOME/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot from $(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').png"
-> Apply
```

Once setup and after taking a couple of screenshots (using win+shift+s), you can see the files in ~/Pictures/Screenshots .

```
% ls -1 ~/Pictures/Screenshots
'Screenshot from 2023-04-24 17:32:36.png'
'Screenshot from 2023-04-24 18:14:57.png'
```

I tested this on Debian 11 (bullseye) using spectacle 20.12.3.

Ref:- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=140137 - I found the above solution here. I just aggregated it into a single post for easy reference. All the credit goes to the original authors.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from *Spectacle* there's also *xfce4-screenshooter* which has the option  [Host on Imgur](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screenshooter/usage#after_capturing):

[image]